# Set the width of dynamically created UITextField in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

This has "Let Me Google That For You" written all over it but I have tried believe me

I am creating a UITextField in a Xamarin iOS Controller and I want to set the Width of the field. I am using constraints to position the various fields but I cannot see how I can position the UITextField with horizontal alignment of centre, on a line by itself AND give it an explicit **width**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this post in the Xamarin Forums, [iOS AutoLayout in C# without using Interface Builder](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/15157/ios-autolayout-in-c-without-using-interface-builder). It has examples of LayoutConstraints and applying them from C#.

The one I needed was NSLayoutAttribute.Width. You would apply it like this

```
View.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(usernameTextBox, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, null, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, 1, 250.0f));
```

If you are using the altogether more friendly FluentLayouts from Stuart Lodge (MVVM Cross) you would apply like this

```
usernameTextBox.Width().EqualTo(250.0f)
```